# Has IntelliJ Community Edition 19.2.4 had a bug introduced with Kotlin 1.3.60 handling multi-platform test names that use back ticks?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

My tests are now (with the 1.3.60 upgrade) reporting a Javascript issue (does not support spaces in the common module test names) even though JS is not a configured target. Only JVM is configured for now. This is new to IntellJ as it behaved perfectly with 1.3.50. Interestingly enough this is clearly an IntellJ issue as Gradle builds the library just fine and even IntelliJ runs the tests marked in red just fine. So it would appear that some code to ignore the spaces in names when JS is not configured has been removed or is not working properly.  Can anyone confirm or refute my theory. If the former I'll file a bug.  If the latter, I'll keep debugging.

Truth in advertising demands that I also confess to having just upgraded my Catalina Macos system to run on a case-sensitive file system whereas it previously was case-insensitive. It would be both bizarre and a bug for this to be relevant, IMHO.

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: Bug already reported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35031

Comment: Problem has been resolved by JetBrains with a release for Kotlin 1.3.61